# Doesn't work make a call

Tags: android

i'm trying to make a call  using  permission action call in code when i click a imagebutton it's doesn't work what i expected did i wrong code or some line missing for this operation plz help me ..

aboutme.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mydetail">
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/callme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_call"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/skill"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/skill" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

androidmainfest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

mainactivity.java:

```
private ImageButton callme;

public void addListenerOnButtonClick(){
        callme = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.callme);
        callme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: 9841******"));
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                startActivity(callIntent);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: update your error log?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass *URI* to *Intent*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + telNumber));
startActivity(intent);
```

Do not forget about to ask for runtime permissions **>=M**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void makeCall(String num) {
    int hasPerm = getPackageManager().checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, getPackageName());
    if (hasPerm == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + num));
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        //"Permission denied! ask for permission here :- need to change your phone permission in setting."
    }
}
```

Comment: On which device you are testing . also what Api level ?

Answer (score 0):

**Do like this**

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        final String[] NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE};

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(DialerHomeActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"
                    + yourNumber)));

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DialerHomeActivity.this,NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS, 123);


        }
    }
    else
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"
                + yourNumber)));
    }
```

if version>=M then first give runtime permission